# Adapting Solution of Second Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am interested in solving the following system of differential equations
\begin{equation}
 \ddot{z}_j = \sum_{k\neq j}^n\frac{2\dot{z}_j\dot{z}_k}{z_j-z_k},\qquad \forall j\in\{1,\dots,n\},
\end{equation}
for $n$ even and initial conditions satisfying
\begin{equation}
 {z}_{j+n/2}(0) = {z}_{j}^{-1}(0),\qquad \forall j\in\{1,\dots,n/2\}.
\end{equation}

I have found the following solution that works except for the fact that it does not satisfy the initial conditions (for $n>2$):
\begin{equation}
 {z}_{j}(t) = a + b e^{2\pi i \frac{j}{n}}(t-c)^{\frac{1}{n}}.
\end{equation}

I am looking for a way to modify this solution in order to be able to satisfy the initial condition, but haven't been successful. Any hints or references would be very welcome.

Comment: Do you mean $2/n$ rather then $n/2$?  Also don't you need $2n$ initial conditions in total.

Comment: @user121049 I did indeed mean $n/2$, sorry for the typo. To determine the solution completely one would need to specify $2n$ conditions, so if making up additional conditions allows one to find a solution that satisfies the initial conditions specified in particular that works for me.